# Are Bitbucket pipelines steps run consecutively?

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm learning about docker, and bitbucket pipelines, so forgive my noob question ahead of time. Are steps within a pipeline ran consecutivetly?
For example:

```
image:
  name: my-imge:and-version
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: first
        script:
          - echo 'something' >> my_file.txt
     - step:
        name: second
        script:
          - cat my_file.txt
```

Assuming `my_file.txt` doesn't exist in my docker container.

Will the second step pass or fail?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the steps are run sequentially.

The second step will run only if the first one is finished successfuly

Steps can also be run in parallel if required. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/parallel-steps-946606807.html

Comment: Will the second one run correctly though? Even if the first one passes?

Comment: Yes it will pass because the file is created in the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, steps are run sequentially. If a step passes, the next one will begin executing.

But your second step, in this case, will fail.

Each step runs in its own Docker container. No state is automatically passed through. You will need to configure it yourself.

For example, if you'd like your second step to have access to 'my_file.txt', you need to define that as [an artifact](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/using-artifacts-in-steps-935389074.html).

To make your script above pass. You could use a configuration like this:

```
image:
  name: my-imge:and-version
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: first
        artifacts:
          - *.txt # Copy found .txt files into *all* sebsequent steps.
        script:
          - echo 'something' >> my_file.txt
    - step:
        name: second
        script:
          - cat my_file.txt # my_file.txt has been copied from step 1 as an artifact.
```

Or alternatively, put both commands in a single step.

```
image:
  name: my-imge:and-version
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: first and second combined
        script:
          - echo 'something' >> my_file.txt
          - cat my_file.txt
```